# TeXstudio macro script : how to move the cursor to specified position?

Tags: latex, qtscript, texstudio

For example, I want to write the following macro in script in TeXstudio(**using QtScript**):

```
%SCRIPT   
editor.write("\\textcolor{red}{}")
```

After invoking this macro, I want the cursor to move into the second pair of curly braces automatically. How can I modify my code to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%SCRIPT
txt = "\\textcolor{red}{}"
cursor.insertText(txt)
cursor.movePosition(1,cursorEnums.Left)
```